# import excel file and save in mysql database

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have a problem in uploading excel files in my database...

I am looking for a code that allows my project to browse for the excel file then save all the data in my database and automatically appear it in my data grid view..

I have been searching codes for about two days and I already tried some of them but still I didn't find codes that fits to my problem..

I tried this code.. but it didn't work fine.

```vb
Dim conko As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

Try
    Dim fBrowse As New OpenFileDialog
    With fBrowse
        .Filter = "Excel files(*.xls)|*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        .FilterIndex = 1
        .Title = "Import data from Excel file"
    End With
    If fBrowse.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim fname As String
        fname = fBrowse.FileName
        Dim ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source= " & fname & ";" & " Extended Properties= ""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"""
        Dim Connection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
        Connection.Open()

        Dim CollectionName As String = "Tables"
        Dim dt As DataTable = Connection.GetSchema(CollectionName)

        Dim TableRow As DataRow
        For Each TableRow In dt.Rows
            If TableRow.Item("userlog").ToString.IndexOf("$") = TableRow.Item("userlog").ToString.Length - 1 Then
                Console.WriteLine(TableRow.Item("userlog").ToString)
            End If
        Next

        Connection.Close()

    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can reference this PHP code and see how it works in VBA:

[Read excel file and store it to mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778354/read-excel-file-and-store-it-to-mysql-database)

Okay, I found some other links:

http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?46880-vba-code-import-table-excel-to-mysql

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,100302

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/734639-mysql-excel-visual-basic-applications.html